# how to change starting position of progressBar

Tags: delphi, winapi

how can I change a starting position of progressBar with setting a part of progressBar empty for example 0 -> 50, and start the progress ( green color) from 50. , so is there any specific method to do that?

Comment: Why don't you put two progressbars next to eachother and leave the left one empty?

Comment: Suggestion: Write your own lightweight component inheriting from TGraphicControl, and write your own paint method.  See: http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc061102b.htm

Answer (score 5):

<strike>The position of a progress bar is determined by its [`Position`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TProgressBar.Position) property. So, supposing that the limits of the progress bar are `0` and `100`, and you wish to start at the middle, set `Position` to `50`.</strike>

You tried to change `Min`, but I suspect that you don't understand what `Min` and `Max` do. They merely define the scale for the `Position` property. So, when `Position` is equal to `Min`, then the progress bar is empty, when `Position` is equal to `Max` then the progress bar is full. And values of `Position` in between `Min` and `Max` specify partially complete progress.

Mathematically, the proportion complete of a progress bar is given by this formula:

```
(Position-Min) / (Max-Max)
```

So, `Min` and `Max` just allow you to define a convenient scale for which to specify the proportion complete. For instance, if your progress is naturally expressed as a percentage, you might set `Min` to `0` and `Max` to `100`. Alternatively, if you are measuring the progress of a file transfer you might set `Min` to `0` and `Max` to be the total number of bytes to be transferred.

---

In the comments you refine the question by stating:

> I want to set the first middle of progress bar empty for example 0 -> 50, and start the progress ( green color) from 50.

That is not possible with a plain vanilla progress bar. A progress bar fills up from empty to full.

The user interface that you are looking for is not possible with the standard control. You would need to paint the progress bar yourself, not terribly hard to do. If you want it to look like the native control you can use the theme API to paint it.

Comment: Okay, but I want to set the first middle of progressBar empty for example 0 -> 50, and start the progress ( green color) from 50. I don't know how to do that with position property.

Comment: Well, that wasn't obvious from the question. I assumed that you wanted to do something that was possible with the standard control. It seems that is not the case.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I will add this information to my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a compound progressbar with two normal progressbars.

Put them next to each other and make the left one (PBarEmpty) overlap the right one (PBarActive). The right one has half the width as the left one.

Use the code below to set the position (0..100).

[image]
[image]

```
procedure TForm1.SetProgress(progress: Integer);
begin
  if (progress = 0) then
  begin
    PBarEmpty.Width := 2*PBarActive.Width;
    PBarActive.Position := 0;
  end
  else begin
    if PBarEmpty.Width <> PBarActive.Width then
       PBarEmpty.Width := PBarActive.Width;
    PBarActive.Position := progress;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It looks a bit gnarly at the join. I don't think it's too hard to paint your own control using theme api.

Comment: But I don't know the number of current values in my application, it depends on another value that the user enter before executing application, it can be 1 , 2 .. It's a good solution but I think it is not suitable for my application.

Comment: @Emily, if you call the method with a percent value, you are good to use this as is. This is only a code prototype, you can laborate with the parameters as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can do this with any of the standard VCL components.

The TMS [TAdvProgressBar](http://tmssoftware.com/site/advprogr.asp) (not the TAdvProgress component) allows you to set levels on the progress bar. So for example, level 0 is up to 50%, level 1 up to 70%, etc. Each level can have a different background colour.

I just tried it here and I set the Level0 colours to white, then the level 1 percentage to 50 and the colour to lime. Setting the stacked property to True gives you this effect:

[image: TAdvProgressBar]

Comment: Good idea but this is a commercial tool that the OP probably does not own.

Comment: @WarrenP Thanks, just offering an option.